# Are images of isometries of the plane under regular parametrizations of the cylinder themselves isometries of the cylinder?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

And more generally, actually:

Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular surface locally isometric to the plane and suppose a regular parametrization of $M$ is $\phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to M$ given by $(u, v) \mapsto (x(u, v), y(u, v), z(u, v))$, that sends every point in the plane to a point of $M$. Define another map $Q: \mathbb{R}^2 \to M $ in the following manner:

$$\mathbb{R}^2 \ni p \mapsto \phi(A(p))  $$

where $A(p)$ is an arbitrary isometry of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (and also $\phi$ is chosen carefully enough that it has the same coefficients of the fundamental form as the plane). Is it true that $Q$ is an isometry of $M$? If so, can the reuslt be generalized to "images of isometries under regular parametrizations are themselves isometries"? And again, if that's true, how would I state this for riemannian manifolds in general?

Comment: You mean *locally* isometric to the plane. I mean, a cylinder is not globally isometric to the plane :)

Comment: You're right, thanks! I've corrected it

Comment: Here's an important hint: Is $\phi$ itself a (local) isometry?

Comment: @TedShifrin Since they are locally isometric, yes, right (the coefficients of the first fundamental form have to be the same)? And since the composition of isometries is an isometry, we're done. Is that all?

Comment: Well, you didn't specify that your parametrization was carefully chosen. If it's not, ....

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right... I wanted to generalize too much and wasn't careful enough with my wording. I'll edit my question. But the same remais true for higher dimensional cases, correct? (by that I mean that images of isometries for two isometric riemannian manifolds are still isometries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been answered in the comments.